# how to run a python script, only when user is not actively working?

Tags: python, cpu, python-idle

i want to run a very long working python script, and its hard on the CPU.
there is a way to find out if the user is actively working? (moving mouse and keyboard?)

Edit: running on windows only. priority is not a good idea, still taking a lot of CPU.

Comment: Process prioritization and management is generally the responsibility of the OS.  What OS are you running on?  You should be able to use a mechanism provided by it to set your job's process priority.

Comment: As @sr2222 says - it's up to the OS to decide things of that nature - you can give hints but short of that... nope

Comment: @sr222: in many cases you want to keep the system super-responsive and ready, even if the user doesn't continuously doing "work".

Comment: @BerryTsakala What does that have to do with anything?  Yes, that is a reason why you'd want to be able to prioritize your processes.  That doesn't touch on how you'd accomplish that goal in the slightest.

Comment: @sr2^4 I'd sample the CPU or I/O for inactivity, or, best, hook to the system's screensaver event. "nice" is good for prioratizing CPU, but it can't predict if your program involve many heavy I/O ops OR specifically UI, that essentially what bothers the user.

Answer (score 3):

If you run the script as low priority (`nice 20 python foo.py`), it will be running all the time, but won't have much of a noticeable impact on higher priority processes (which will be all of them, because 20 is the lowest priority level).